# Como realizar uma query com interação has_many em Ruby on Rails

Tags: query, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Estou com dificuldade de realizar uma busca com interações has_many no ruby on rails. Objetivo é buscar todos os veículos que não tem nenhuma multa do tipo 'cara'... O problema é que a query que eu fiz ainda retorna vários veículos com o tipo 'cara'. Estou tentando realizar a busca assim:

```
veiculos = Veiculo.joins(:multas).where.not(multas: { tipo: 'cara' }).group('veiculos.id')
```

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 0):

```
veiculos = Veiculo.joins(:multas).where.not('multas.tipo = ?', "cara")
```

Comment: Pode explicar o que o código faz? É a solução para a questão colocada?

Comment: A variable veiculos é um Active Record que pega todos models Veiculo que tem o model Multa com a column "tipo" com o valor de cara. O código pega a table Veiculos, faz com um join table com a table Multas e dessas pega todas multas que a column tipo são "cara"